# Transition animation does not take place for every text change

Tags: ios

I have added transition animation to `UILabel` for text change.

But it takes place only once when I add it to `layer`.

```
- (IBAction)changeText:(id)sender {
  if (!self.transitionAnimation) {
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.duration = 0.5;
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [self.label.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
    self.transitionAnimation = animation;
  }
  self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text %d",arc4random()];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to have a strong reference to the animation? That reference doesn't get nil'ed out, and hence your control doesn't enter the if block more than once.

Either nil out the `transitionAnimation` property on `didStop`, or don't store a reference at all.

Edit: Also, I don't think you need to have `removedOnCompletion` as `NO`.

Comment: I want to add it only once not every time. May I will add it in viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad.

Comment: You'll have to add it each time you change the text. Why do you want to add it just once?

Comment: Then what is use of removedOnCompletion?